# How to refresh timeline in twitter app in android 

Tags: android, twitter

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.i( "Service connection established","");

            // that's how we get the client side of the IPC connection
            api = com.oreilly.android.otweet.TweetCollectorApi.Stub.asInterface(service);
            try {
                api.addListener(collectorListener);
            /*  Intent i = new Intent(StatusListActivity.this, StatusListActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);*/
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e("", "Failed to add listener", e);
            }
```

Comment: You mean You want to stop service when application stops?

Comment: yes..and also want to update tweets

Answer (score 0):

To stop service when application stops we need to call `unbindService()` in the `onDestroy()`.

Edit:

In your link there are code for this

```
@Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
              super.onDestroy();

              try {
                api.removeListener(collectorListener);
                unbindService(serviceConnection);
              } catch (Throwable t) {
                // catch any issues, typical for destroy routines
                // even if we failed to destroy something, we need to continue destroying
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to unbind from the service", t);
              }

              Log.i(TAG, "Activity destroyed");
            }
```

Comment: yaa this is ok..but unbind service is a method so how to use it

Comment: what happen Sandy@ I am waitting for your possitive response plz help..if u can??

Comment: i have created this in first activity but this is a method where it has to call..not getting properly

Comment: On your first activity when you press back key the first activity automatically destroyed

Comment: but its not working after closing the app, its running again   automatically on the main screen.

Comment: when app is closed after that my timeline will automatically start.refresh and again stat my app

Comment: yaa..after closing first activity app will run again,my first activity is showing Timeline and I want to refresh it again and again automatically

Comment: Did the service stop after first activity finish?

Comment: public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     Log.i("", "Service destroying");
     try {
            api.removeListener(collectorListener);
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            // catch any issues, typical for destroy routines
            // even if we failed to destroy something, we need to continue destroying
            Log.w("", "Failed to unbind from the service", t);
          }

Comment: change binding code like `bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
       Services.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`